# Rails Nested Form Object in other controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, routes, zurb-foundation, nested-resources

After trying to make this work for about 12 hours now, I have to turn to SO for salvation. Here's the scenario.

I'm using zurb foundation 4, and am trying to make a reveal modal ajax form for a nested resource in my dashboard.

I have the following nested resources:

```
  resources :lessons, only: [:index, :edit, :show] do
    resources :notes, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :delete]
  end
```

form at lessons/1/notes/new works fine.

I have a table on my static_pages/home like so:

```
  <table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Student</th>
      <th>Subject</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
<% @lessons.each do |lesson| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= link_to lesson.student.name, lesson %></td>
      <td><%= lesson.subject.name %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'make a note', new_lesson_note_path(lesson), "data-reveal-id"=>"note-for" %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

Under all my markup, I have the following form in a foundation reveal modal:

```
<!--Reveal Form-->
<div id="note-for" class="reveal-modal">
<% @lessons.each do |lesson| %> <--form now associated with proper object-->
  <%= form_for Note.new, :url => new_lesson_note_path(lesson) do |f| %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :content %>
        <%= f.text_area :content %>
      </div>
      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Save", class: "small button"%>
      </div>
  <% end %>
  <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Modal renders fine, submitting the form however throws the following error:

```
No route matches [POST] "/lessons/1/notes/new"
```

I'm seriously at a loss here, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FINALLY!

after 13 hours of tinkering, the solution!

add a loop within the reveal modal div

```
<div id="note-for" class="reveal-modal">
   <% @lessons.each do |lesson| %>
    .......
   <% end %>
</div>
```

ensure notes_controller.rb action is properly formatted

```
  def create
    @lesson = Lesson.find(params[:lesson_id])
    @note = @lesson.notes.build(params[:note])
    if @note.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Lesson noted!' }
      format.js
    end
    else
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
```

and now I'm off to the pub! thanks ole

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you made a misstake with `@lessons` variable. Your are passing, model relation to url helper, instead of model.

For solve it try:

```
#controller
@lesson = Lesson.find(params[:lesson_id])

#view
...
<%= form_for Note.new, :url => new_lesson_note_path(@lesson) do |f| %>
...
```

Comment: I've actually tried this, doesnt work. Good news is however that I've managed to form the proper association through <% @lessons.each do |lesson| %>. Please see the edited code. Only problem now is that it throws a routing error. I think (@lessons) was associating the form with a collection of lessons instead of just the one.

Comment: There's something magical about SO. Ofttimes I would spend hours on a problem. Give up. Beg for help on SO. And as soon as I finish typing my question the solution just pops into my head.